# How to embed a coordinate pair within URL to search OpenStreetMap, Google, Yahoo or Bing Maps

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, bing-maps, html

Is there a way to embed a latitude longitude coordinate pair within a url link to search for a location on either OpenStreetMap, Google and/or Bing Maps?  I'd like to use the url link within Excel, LibreOffice and within an html pages.  I have tables with coordinates that I'd like to configure with a link to show its location on a map, without building an online mapping application.

If not, then is there a simple javascript that I can encapsulate the coordinate within and fetch that from OpenStreetMap, Google and/or Bing Maps?

It seems like the url would be something like the following, but I can't get this to work:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/?30.486,-90.195

Comment: Geohack http://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Leeds&params=53_47_59_N_1_32_57_W_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a way of doing it.  Example: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=12.345&lon=12.345&zoom=17&layers=M
fomr [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8490/how-to-position-at-given-coordinates)

For google there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660201/what-parameters-should-i-use-in-a-google-maps-url-to-go-to-a-lat-lon)

Bing example - http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.02102351~-1.48398532&lvl=16&dir=0&sty=c as taken from the question posted [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10077/create-link-to-bing-maps-with-push-pin-at-the-centre)

Comment: Mark and Paul, I got these to work as links inside a spreadsheet or a standard html page.  But, I noticed that OpenStreetMap doesn't if linked from within a FRAME window of an html page (the map doesn't show up, but the OpenStreetMap menu's do).  To fix that I   The Google link does work from inside a html FRAME window.   To get OpenStreetMaps to work from with a FRAME window, I had to an IFRAME like so... <iframe width="500" height="200" frameborder="0"

Answer (score 4):

These days you can just copy the URL from your browser address bar which should look something like this (with your example coordinates) :

https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/30.486/-90.195

(Note: this dynamically updated '#' character URL structure was introduced some time after the original question was asked)

OpenStreetMap offers quite a lot of other options for linking to the maps, some of which are available by clicking the "Share" button to access a right-hand panel there. These are also described on the [documentation about browsing the map](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Browsing#Sharing_a_link_to_the_maps).

e.g.
https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=30.486&mlon=-90.195#map=16/30.486/-90.195  ...puts a marker at those coordinates

http://osm.org/go/Tu_z5cFR ...as a 'short link' (redirects)

http://osm.org/go/Tu_z5cFR?m ...a 'short link' with marker

You can actually slap in a coordinate pair "30.486,-90.195" with a comma into the search box on the OpenStreetMap homepage, and that gives you a link to click, which dynamically zooms you to that spot, although you can also right click to open the link in a new window at a URL formatted as above.

If you want a frame embeddable map, use the [Share panel 'HTML' option documented here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Export#Embeddable_HTML) which gives you HTML like this:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-90.20224,30.48102,-90.18775,30.49097&amp;layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=30.485995000000003&amp;lon=-90.194995&amp;zoom=15&amp;layers=M">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

Contained with that is a URL like this...

http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-90.20224,30.48102,-90.18775,30.49097&layer=mapnik

All of these URL formats could be generated by Excel using a formula to go from the lat/lon values in two other cells.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you click the Permalink button at the bottom right of the
   screen, it will give you the syntax you want.
   http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=30.486&lon=-90.195&zoom=8&layers=M
   You can chop off the zoom level and layers if you don't need them.
2. http://maps.google.com/maps?q=30.486+-90.195 (the + is necessary)